# Verify appium current activity response

Tags: android-activity, automation, appium, python-appium

I verify launched current activity if it's in browser or in app by comparing with current activity.
`activity = driverAppium.current_activity`

And then I verify if activity matches with browser activity name e.g. org.chromium.browser...

But can I verify the http response on the webpage e.g. `200` or `404`?

With above test always passes even though webpage didn't load or get null response.

Can I verify with current activity and response both?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it what I can think of,

1. *UI prospect* :

   - Capture the screenshot of the webview with 200 response. Let's call it `expectedScreen.png`
   - Capture the screenshot of the under test response(be it 200, 400 etc.). Lets call this `finalScreen.png`
   - Compare both the images to verify/assert.
2. *API prospect* : Since the `Activity` suppose to be displayed shall never/rarely be changed depending on transitions between different activities on your application as designed, so verifying current activity is a less important check during the test. You can rather verify these using API calls and then(if you get proper response) look for presence of elements on screen accordingly.